# How do you set-up Mongo replica set on Kubernetes?

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes

I'd like to set-up a Mongo replica set on Kubernetes. I'd like to have three replicas. This means I'd need to start 3 instances.

Should I start three pods, with Mongo in each one, and use the service the point to the primary? Or should I used a replication controller somehow?

Comment: How does mongodb handle discovery of new workers in the cluster? Are each of the workers configured the same? Can any worker take http requests?

Comment: I'm open to suggestions, but I would expect one primary and 2 secondaries.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**This answer is out of date. I wrote a detailed step-by-step tutorial [here](http://blog.kubernetes.io/2017/01/running-mongodb-on-kubernetes-with-statefulsets.html) using more up to date methods. I highly recommend reading it all.**

In a nutshell, you run a sidecar app to configure the replica set for you, and either use a service per instance or ping the K8s API for the pod IP addresses.

**Example:** This will only work in Google Cloud. You will need to make modifications for other platforms, particularly around the volumes:

1. Follow the example in https://github.com/leportlabs/mongo-k8s-sidecar.git

   - `git clone https://github.com/leportlabs/mongo-k8s-sidecar.git`
   - `cd mongo-k8s-sidecar/example/`
   - `make add-replica ENV=GoogleCloudPlatform` (do this three times)
2. Connect to the replica set via services.

   - `mongodb://mongo-1,mongo-2,mongo-3:27017/dbname_?`
3. You can also use the raw pod IP addresses instead of creating a service per pod

   - Use this https://github.com/thesandlord/kubernetes-pod-ip-finder.git

Comment: Yes, I just read your article. By any chance is this production ready? And I already have a dump of mongo db. Is there any other persistent storage other than Google Cloud and AWS? Flocker doesn't seem to support CoreOs right now.

Comment: Depends on your definition of Production Ready. IMO, there is more that needs to be done before it is ready, mostly around security and performance (sharding). 

Could you run this in production? Sure, and you probably will be ok. It's equivalent to running a normal MongoDB replica set, and if that works for you then this will be equal. In fact, it will be better than a normal replica set as it is easier to manage and kubernetes will keep it running smoothly.

As for storage options, take a look here: http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/persistent-volumes.html#types-of-persistent-volumes

Comment: Alright, by any chance do you have an idea on how to dump your `mongodump` on Google Cloud Storage?

Comment: Sure! Can you post it as a separate question, I don't think I can answer it on  the comments. I would probably reccomend https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/ which allows you to mount a storage bucket like a directory.

Comment: Note this answer specifically relates to the Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: Just a note to says, don't use the mongo-k8s-sidecar in a Production environment as it has potential problems. See my main answer added, "Just as a heads-up..."

Comment: Hi @Sandeep, this implementation is really helpful. I see you use a headless service but what if I need to use an external application to connect to this mongo env (an app outside the k8s cluster)? Also how should I handle authentication? Thanks

Comment: I tried to use your example from your article but K8s complains about a few fields. Not sure if it is related to the odd formatting but I figured I'd let you know. Cheers.

Comment: Is there any follow-up post/update on this? Created another Stack Overflow question already on this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64453545/11478452

Answer (score 6):

Typically, to set up a clustered set of nodes like mongo with replicas sets, you would create a `Service` that tracks the pods under the service name (so for example, create a MongoDB replication controller with a tag `mongodb`, and a `Service` tracking those instances)
The Service can then be queried for its members (using the API server, you can look up the nodes with

`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)" --cacert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt https://kubernetes/api/v1/namespaces/default/endpoints/mongodb`

where mongodb is your selector on the name of the service.

that returns a JSON object with a bunch of fields, so a good way to parse these easily is to use jq  https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

piping the curl command into a jq query like

`jq '.subsets[].addresses[]' | jq '{ip: .ip, host:.targetRef.name}'` will return the IP and hostnames of the mongodb instances in your cluster.

So now you know who is in the cluster and you can create the replica set in your init script. 
Obviously here that means you need to start the `Service` first, your startup script needs to wait for all the nodes to be up and registered with the service, and then you can proceed. 
If you use one image, with one script, it will run n each node, so you need to check that the replica set does not exists already or handle errors. The first pod to register should do the work.
Another option is to run all nodes as single nodes, then run a separate bootstrapping script that will create the replica set.

Finally, then you call the mongodb cluster, you will need to make sure you specify the url with replica set name as an option:

`mongodb://mongodb:27017/database?replicaSet=replicaSetName`

Since you don't know the IP of the master, you would call it through the service `mongodb` which will load balance the requests to one of the nodes, and if you don't specify the replica set name, you will end up with connection errors as only the master can get write requests.

Obviously this is not a step by step tutorial, but i hope that gets you started.

Comment: Thanks @MrE. I get the impression that I'll need to run a standard service and controller for the database. But, I'll need an extra pod who's job is to initiate the replica set.

Comment: since 1.3.4 there are now init containers in kubernetes. So far I have been usign the `postStart` hook to do this setup but init containers seem like a better option.

Answer (score 2):

This is the example I'm currently running.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: mongo
  name: mongo-svc1
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
  selector:
    type: mongo-rs-A
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: mongo
  name: mongo-svc2
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
  selector:
    type: mongo-rs-B
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: mongo
  name: mongo-svc3
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
  selector:
    type: mongo-rs-C
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController

metadata:
  name: mongo

spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    name: mongo-nodea
    role: mongo
    environment: test

  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: mongo-nodea
        role: mongo
        environment: test
        type: mongo-rs-A
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mongo-nodea
          image: mongo
          command:
            - mongod
            - "--replSet"
            - rsABC
            - "--smallfiles"
            - "--noprealloc"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mongo-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /data/db
      volumes:
        - name: mongo-persistent-storage
          flocker:
            datasetName: FlockerMongoVolSetA
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController

metadata:
  name: mongo-1

spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    name: mongo-nodeb
    role: mongo
    environment: test

  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: mongo-nodeb
        role: mongo
        environment: test
        type: mongo-rs-B
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mongo-nodeb
          image: mongo
          command:
            - mongod
            - "--replSet"
            - rsABC
            - "--smallfiles"
            - "--noprealloc"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mongo-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /data/db
      volumes:
        - name: mongo-persistent-storage
          flocker:
            datasetName: FlockerMongoVolSetB
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController

metadata:
  name: mongo-2

spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    name: mongo-nodec
    role: mongo
    environment: test

  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: mongo-nodec
        role: mongo
        environment: test
        type: mongo-rs-C
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mongo-nodec
          image: mongo
          command:
            - mongod
            - "--replSet"
            - rsABC
            - "--smallfiles"
            - "--noprealloc"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mongo-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /data/db
      volumes:
        - name: mongo-persistent-storage
          flocker:
            datasetName: FlockerMongoVolSetC


kubectl --kubeconfig=clusters/k8s-mongo/kubeconfig get po,svc -L type,role,name
NAME            READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       TYPE         ROLE      NAME
mongo-1-39nuw   1/1       Running   0          1m        mongo-rs-B   mongo     mongo-nodeb
mongo-2-4tgho   1/1       Running   0          1m        mongo-rs-C   mongo     mongo-nodec
mongo-rk9n8     1/1       Running   0          1m        mongo-rs-A   mongo     mongo-nodea
NAME         CLUSTER_IP   EXTERNAL_IP   PORT(S)     SELECTOR          AGE       TYPE      ROLE      NAME
kubernetes   10.3.0.1     <none>        443/TCP     <none>            21h       <none>    <none>    <none>
mongo-svc1   10.3.0.28    <none>        27017/TCP   type=mongo-rs-A   1m        <none>    <none>    mongo
mongo-svc2   10.3.0.56    <none>        27017/TCP   type=mongo-rs-B   1m        <none>    <none>    mongo
mongo-svc3   10.3.0.47    <none>        27017/TCP   type=mongo-rs-C   1m        <none>    <none>    mongo
```

On the Primary node I am going into mongo shell

> rs.status()
>   rs.initiate()
>   rs.add("10.3.0.56:27017")

I'm currently running into this issue where I'm stuck in Secondary and Startup statuses for the two nodes without a primary.

```
rs.status()
{
    "set" : "rsABC",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-01-21T22:51:33.216Z"),
    "myState" : 2,
    "term" : NumberLong(1),
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "mongo-rk9n8:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 242,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1453416638, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(1)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2016-01-21T22:50:38Z"),
            "infoMessage" : "could not find member to sync from",
            "configVersion" : 2,
            "self" : true
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "10.3.0.56:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 0,
            "stateStr" : "STARTUP",
            "uptime" : 45,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                "t" : NumberLong(-1)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2016-01-21T22:51:28.639Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(40),
            "configVersion" : -2
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Why do we have three services for a MongoDB replica set? Isn't the best practice is to make it work with one service?

Comment: hey @Nawaz-CloudBoost.io I'm still experimenting but my early guess was that these services were needed so that a router could possibly figure out which node to direct the writes to when leaders change.

Comment: Hey @Nawaz-CloudBoost.io are you on the kubernetes slack group? I'm discussing the issue there you can find me "stephenitis"

Comment: No, unfortunately I'm not. Did you get any help?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here at the link below.  In kubernetes, create the service addresses then the controllers and the replicaset initiation can be easily generated....https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/running-mongodb-as-a-microservice-with-docker-and-kubernetes

Comment: Post the relevant information about the link please

Answer (score 0):

@Stephen Nguyen

I just copy your case and create namespace test for it(I change your yaml file accordingly), and initialize my mongo rs by :

```
rs.initiate({
     "_id" : "rsABC",
     "members" : [
          {
               "_id" : 0,
               "host" : "mongo-svc1.test:27017",
               "priority" : 10
          },
          {
               "_id" : 1,
               "host" : "mongo-svc2.test:27017",
               "priority" : 9
          },
          {
               "_id" : 2,
               "host" : "mongo-svc3.test:27017",
                "arbiterOnly" : true
          }
     ]
})
```

It seems it does work:

```
> rs.status()
{
        "set" : "rsABC",
        "date" : ISODate("2016-05-10T07:45:25.975Z"),
        "myState" : 2,
        "term" : NumberLong(2),
        "syncingTo" : "mongo-svc1.test:27017",
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "mongo-svc1.test:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 657,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1462865715, 2),
                                "t" : NumberLong(2)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2016-05-10T07:35:15Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2016-05-10T07:45:25.551Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2016-05-10T07:45:25.388Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "electionTime" : Timestamp(1462865715, 1),
                        "electionDate" : ISODate("2016-05-10T07:35:15Z"),
                        "configVersion" : 1
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "name" : "mongo-svc2.test:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 1171,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1462865715, 2),
                                "t" : NumberLong(2)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2016-05-10T07:35:15Z"),
                        "syncingTo" : "mongo-svc1.test:27017",
                        "configVersion" : 1,
                        "self" : true
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "name" : "mongo-svc3.test:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 7,
                        "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
                        "uptime" : 657,
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2016-05-10T07:45:25.549Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2016-05-10T07:45:23.969Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "configVersion" : 1
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

I add mongo node by the service name.

Answer (score -2):

I'm using this as a solution. Its NOT production ready yet.

Setup MongoDB Replication

Get all the MongoDB pod IP `kubectl describe pod <PODNAME> | grep IP | sed -E 's/IP:[[:space:]]+//'`

and...

Run `kubectl exec -i <POD_1_NAME> mongo`

and ...

```
rs.initiate({ 
     "_id" : "cloudboost", 
     "version":1,
     "members" : [ 
          {
               "_id" : 0,
               "host" : "<POD_1_IP>:27017",
               "priority" : 10
          },
          {
               "_id" : 1,
               "host" : "<POD_2_IP>:27017",
               "priority" : 9
          },
          {
               "_id" : 2,
               "host" : "<POD_3_IP>:27017",
               "arbiterOnly" : true
          }
     ]
});
```

For Example :

```
rs.initiate({  
     "_id" : "cloudboost",
     "version":1,
     "members" : [ 
          {
               "_id" : 0,
               "host" : "10.244.1.5:27017",
               "priority" : 10
          },
          {
               "_id" : 1,
               "host" : "10.244.2.6:27017",
               "priority" : 9
          },
          {
               "_id" : 2,
               "host" : "10.244.3.5:27017",
               "arbiterOnly" : true
          }
     ]
});
```

Please Note : IP's can be different for your cluster.

**TODO :** Create a headless service to discover the nodes automatically and initialize a replicaset.

Comment: Pod IP can change, you should not you them as stable identity.

Comment: I know, This is why this is a non-production solution. :)

Comment: Great stuff! Did you need to shard?

Comment: No, This is just a replcaset.